# Why does this query return unwanted rows

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returns rows with `latitude = 0` and `longitude = 0`

```
SELECT `id`, 
              `first_name`, 
              `last_name`, 
              `address`, 
              `latitude`, 
              `longitude` 
              FROM `members` 
              WHERE (`temp` != 'on' OR `temp` IS NULL) 
              AND (`backup` != 'on' OR `backup` IS NULL) 
              AND (`latitude` IS NOT NULL OR `latitude` != 0 OR `latitude` != '') 
              AND (`longitude` != 0 OR `longitude` != '' OR `longitude` IS NOT NULL) 
              AND `address` != '' 
              AND `type_id` = 1
              AND `first_name` != ''
```

query is returning rows where lat/long have 0 value - Datatype = VARCHAR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `and`, not `or`:

```
          WHERE (`temp` != 'on' OR `temp` IS NULL) 
          AND (`backup` != 'on' OR `backup` IS NULL) 
          AND (`latitude` IS NOT NULL and `latitude` != 0 and `latitude` != '') 
          AND (`longitude` != 0 and `longitude` != ''and `longitude` IS NOT NULL) 
          AND `address` != '' 
          AND `type_id` = 1
          AND `first_name` != ''
```

`Latitude` may be 0 (failing that condition), but it is not `NULL` -- passing that one.

Comment: @maximl337 you can thank Gordon by accepting his answer.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Yes I know, I have to wait 11 mins before I can accept it :)